# ios Reside menu managing right and left menu content

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, residemenu

i am working on an application where i needed to have both right and left menu. i am using reside menu and by changing _contentViewInPortraitOffsetCenterX to 70.f, i am getting my desired result but there is a problem when i am showing right menu.
please see attach screenshots for these. the problem is that right side view getting inside my content view, i would like it to move to more right so i get it same as left menu.

[image: left menu]

[image: Right menu]

Comment: please help regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```